# Android timeline aka lines between two views

Tags: android, user-interface

I am trying to implement a layout which is able to draw lines between views. Here is a sample picture of a library that does the job but seems outdated, just like other solutions I've found:

[image: sample picture]

Any ideas or code samples?

Comment: What do you mean by 'draws lines between views'?

Comment: @degs the lines you can see between the green points of the sample picture

Comment: Build a `Canvas`, and just draw on it

Comment: why don't you use **Google's Material Design steppers** ? you can read more about [here](https://material.io/guidelines/components/steppers.html) and there's a lot of github projects you can take from and modify them according to your needs

Comment: @SígvardrÓlavrsson didn't know steppers existed but that's exactly what i was searching for, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @SígvardrÓlavrsson pointed out, google material steppers represent the best solution here: https://material.io/guidelines/components/steppers.html

Comment: The link is broken.